# EDATE comparable in SQL Server? -- Next Anniversary Date Calculation

Tags: sql, ssms, datediff

Can someone help me figure out a formula to be used in SQL Server similar to the Excel formula pasted below?

=EDATE(date,(DATEDIF(date,TODAY(),"y")+1)*12)

I want to capture the next anniversary date.

```
ID, Date, Next Anniversary
123, 01/12/20, 01/12/21
234, 05/25/17, 05/25/20
```

The information I have is ID and date. I want to determine next anniversary date.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Don't make people guess on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by an "anniversary date"? Isn't that just the date +1 year?

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated.

Comment: @larnu Yes. But what about a date of 05/25/17. The next anniversary date is 05/25/20 (not 05/25/18).

Comment: So what you're actually describing is the next date that is after the current date, that shares the same month and day?

Comment: Exactly. @larnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you could achieve this fairly easily with `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`, and a `CASE` expression if the generated date is less than the current date:

```
SELECT YourDate,
       CASE WHEN V.NextDate < CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) THEN DATEADD(YEAR, 1, V.NextDate) ELSE V.NextDate END AS NextDate
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'20190101')), --This would actually be your table
            (CONVERT(date,'20170709')),
            (CONVERT(date,'20160229')), --Leap year
            (CONVERT(date,'20181219')))YT(YourDate)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, YT.YourDate, GETDATE()),YT.YourDate)))V(NextDate);
```